# 2147217833 String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hi Have an error occuring when I try to update a record via stored procedure.
The error I get is 2147217833 String or binary data would be truncated.

I've done a length on each of the fields that I'm inserted and they should be fitting comfortably in to the the database fields - i.e. the length isn't greater that the column specifications.

Completely baffled at the moment - any other reasons why this error might occur?

Thanks,

```
Set objReturnParam = objComm.CreateParameter("Return",adInteger,adParamReturnValue)
Set objRiskIDParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@riskID",adBigInt,adParamInput)   
Set objControlsDescriptionParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@ControlsDescription",adVarChar,adParamInput,5000)
Set objTreatmentParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Treatment",adVarChar,adParamInput,5000)
Set objControlsParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Controls",adVarChar,adParamInput,10)
Set objPriorityParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Priority",adVarChar,adParamInput,6)
Set objProbabilityParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Probability",adVarChar,adParamInput,6)
Set objImpactParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Impact",adVarChar,adParamInput,6)
Set objScoreParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@Score",adInteger,adParamInput)
Set objReviewTimeframeParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@ReviewTimeframe",adVarChar,adParamInput,6)
Set objReviewDateParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@ReviewDate",adDate,adParamInput)
Set objDateReviewedParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@DateReviewed",adDate,adParamInput)
Set objReviewerIDParam = objComm.CreateParameter("@ReviewerID",adInteger,adParamInput)      


objComm.Parameters("@riskID") = lRiskID
objComm.Parameters("@ControlsDescription") = strControlsDescription
objComm.Parameters("@Treatment") = strTreatment
objComm.Parameters("@Controls") = strControls
objComm.Parameters("@Priority") = strPriority
objComm.Parameters("@Probability") = strProbability
objComm.Parameters("@Impact") = strImpact
objComm.Parameters("@Score") = iScore
objComm.Parameters("@ReviewTimeframe") = strReviewTimeframe
objComm.Parameters("@ReviewDate") = cStr(Year(dReviewDate)) + "-" + cStr(Month(dReviewDate)) + "-" + cStr(Day(dReviewDate)) + " 00:00:00"
objComm.Parameters("@DateReviewed") = cStr(Year(Date)) + "-" + cStr(Month(Date)) + "-" + cStr(Day(Date)) + " 00:00:00"
objComm.Parameters("@ReviewerID") = Cstr(Session("UserID"))
```

when I output each of the variables that I'm trying to update, the length of each is:

lRiskID: 2
strControlsDescription: 6
strTreatment: 6
strControls: 4
strPriority: 0
strProbability: 1
strImpact: 1
iScore: 1
strReviewTimeframe: 0
Reviewdate19
dateReviewed19
reviewerid2

```
[ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CONTROLS_DESCRIPTION] [varchar](5000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[TREATMENT] [varchar](5000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[PRIORITY] [varchar](6) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[PROBABILITY] [varchar](6) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[IMPACT] [varchar](6) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[SCORE] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[REVIEW_TIMEFRAME] [varchar](6) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[PROPOSED_REVIEW_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DATE_REVIEWED] [datetime] NULL,
[REVIEWER_ID] [int] NULL,
```

Comment: Can you share the schema and code? You are most likely performing a cast/convert/substring/etc. or possibly getting implicit conversions to/from unicode, or possibly something else. Hard to tell without seeing the code/schema.

Comment: Ok, that helps, but what are you calling to actually write the data to the server and is there any code in that other than insert...values?  i.e. it would appear that you are building an ADO command object and populating it's parameters collection - what are you calling to write that to the server (i.e. cmd.Execute('what procedure'), and can you share any code included in that procedure declaration (i.e. the param interface and anything before the actual insert statement)?

Comment: is there any reason for casting date to string before assigning to datetime type? why not just do objComm.Parameters("@ReviewDate") = dReviewDate objComm.Parameters("@DateReviewed") = Date

Comment: could you add the stored proc code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without schema and code, it's be hard.

Random thoughts:

- Are you concatenating, or using CAST/varchar without a length?
- Do you have trailing spaces (for example, LEN ignores trailing spaces)
- Or is there an audit trigger?

Edit, after code added

Where does @Controls go? There is no column...

To me, this implies the truncate error is not for this table

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter declarations do not all match the data types of your table. You're using adBigInt for a numeric (use adNumeric), adInteger for a tinyint (use adTinyInt).
It looks like you're in VB6, and in VB6 the adDate datatype was used for Access. For updating a SQL Server DB you need to use adDBTimeStamp as the parameter datatype instead.

http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ado/quickref/command_createparameter.html